# Replace match last instance of pattern in a string

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to only show the value after the - as shown below.

```
    $(function(){
        var aa = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS-TUVEXYZ";
        var bb = aa.substring(aa.indexOf("-") + 1);
        $('#one').text(bb);
    });

    $(function(){
        var cc = "ABC-DEFGHIJ-KLMNOPQRS-TUVEXYZ";
        var dd = cc.substring(cc.indexOf("-") + 1);
        $('#two').text(dd);
    });
```

this outputs

```
<div id="one">TUVEXYZ</div>
<div id="two">DEFGHIJ-KLMNOPQRS-TUVEXYZ</div>
```

The first one works as there is only one dash however when there is multiple dashes my code doesn't work as it just looks for the first -. How would I go about looking for the last - only?

eg If my code was working like I want it to I would expect my end result to look like this.

```
<div id="one">TUVEXYZ</div>
<div id="two">TUVEXYZ</div>
```

Comment: _"I have a regex"_ - No you don't. There's no regex anywhere in the code shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use lastIndexOf

```
var dd = cc.substring(cc.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: What would happen if there is no dash in the string? Would it still work?

Comment: `lastIndexOf` will return -1 so your substring will be the same string .

Comment: sorry, read my edited comment. If your substring is equal to your original string then there was no match.

Answer (score 4):

Using regex:

```
var myregexp = /[^-]*$/;
var result = myregexp.exec(subject)[0];
```

This regex matches any number of non-dash characters, anchored to the end of the string, which effectively matches everything that follows after the last dash (or the entire string if there is no dash).

Answer (score 0):

This might be the regex you are looking for :)

```
var.replace( /(?:.*)\-(.*?)$/, $1 ); // or "$1", not really shure in JS
```